# Use WCF to send XML with tags not escaped

Tags: xml, wcf, wsdl

I would like to use WCF to send XML in for inserting records into an internal database table.  This XML needs to be in any style (not serialized up front as a datacontract).  Also, the point of having this service is to allow any Client of ours to send in the XML data, which means universal input methods are a must (for those Clients who aren't using Visual Studio for example). When attempting this, the XML tags are escaped, effectivetely making the payload space used over 50% larger.

```
<Payload></Payload>
```

vs

```
&lt;Payload&gt;&lt;/Payload&gt;
```

Since I want to allow for mass amounts of data to be sent, and because of the higher amount of space being used (because of escaping the tags), this isn't practical.

I've tried to use the CDATA encapsulation (`<![CDATA[<Payload></Payload>]]>`), however, the tags are still escaped (`&lt;![CDATA[&lt;Payload&gt;&lt;/Payload&gt;]]&gt;`).

From other articles, I understand you can pass the parameter of type XElement, but when I try that, the Client code is saying, "Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'."  It doesn't sound like it would allow for those people who don't use VB.NET or C# to use this parameter as well.

Also from other articles, people have said you can use Stream as the input parameter datatype or a byte array.  However, again those who don't have VB.NET or C# couldn't use these datatypes.  If they could too, it really doesn't seem practical to force them to use them.  XML input is all I would like to ask them to pass in.

Is there any other way (when using a Web.Config file instead of locally hosted server code) to allow for any XML to be sent as a parameter which canbe inputed as plain XML, but at the same time making it possible for anyone to call it (who don't have Visual Studio for example)?

This is my third day working on this solution and I'm starting to lose hope.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer which worked for me.

I found out that using an input datatype of XElement was the key.  Since I couldn't expect it to be universally accepted however (for those not using Visual Studio and couldn't create an XElement object for example), I used Fiddler to find out what was being wrapped around the regular POST (using the XElement object).  I then wrapped that same wrapper around a string, and sent the data using HttpWebRequest.

```
    Dim PreSendData As String = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/""><s:Body><ProcessXMLPayload_XElement xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/""><XML>"
Dim PostSendData As String = "</XML></ProcessXMLPayload_XElement></s:Body></s:Envelope>"

Dim thePayLoad As String = _
   "<Payload xmlns="""">" & _
   "<PayloadDetails>" & _
   "<Dependencies>" & _
   "<Dependency>" & _
   "<ParentTable>Guests</ParentTable>" & _
   "</Dependency>" & _
   "</Dependencies>" & _
   "</PayloadDetails>" & _
   "</Payload>"

Dim myWriter As StreamWriter = Nothing
Dim url As String = "http://TestServer/webservices/TestService/TestService.svc/soapService"
Dim myReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
myReq.Method = "POST"
Dim xmlToPost As String = PreSendData & thePayLoad & PostSendData
myReq.ContentLength = xmlToPost.Length
myReq.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
myReq.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", """http://tempuri.org/IService/ProcessXMLPayload_XElement""")

Try
    myWriter = New StreamWriter(myReq.GetRequestStream())
    ' POST to the server
    myWriter.Write(xmlToPost)
Catch e As Exception
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
Finally
    myWriter.Close()
End Try

Dim objResponse As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(myReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
Dim result As String
Using sr As New StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream())
    ' read the response
    result = sr.ReadToEnd()
    sr.Close()
End Using
' send response to the console
Console.WriteLine(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the event that the web service definition, defines the operation input as a string (xsd:string), then the .net framework will escape the XML payload.  If, on the other hand, the service is defined with an operation input parameter of any (xsd:any) then the service will not escape the XML.

The following code sample shows the definition of a property with the XmlAnyElementAttribute:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute(Order = 2)]
public System.Xml.XmlElement Any
{
    get
    {
        return this.anyField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.anyField = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  Can you tell me how I would tell my WCF service to use 'any' instead of 'string' then?

Comment: You need to specify the XmlAnyElementAttribute for the member.  Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyelementattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm just not following on how I could use XmlAnyElementAttribute in my WCF service.  Is this somehow used in my ServiceContract/OperationContract area, within the code behind the service (which is compiled into the DLL), or within the web.config file?  Can you please elaborate, as I'm spinning my wheels over here.  Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You need to add the xmlanyelement attribute to the member in your code (not config).  I added a code sample to the answer above.

Comment: Sorry, still a noobie with WCF.  I assume you were speaking of being a DataMember?  Is so, how can I expose that as the datatype in the OperationContract Function I'm using (currently only able to handle a string)?:

 <OperationContract()> _
 <WebInvoke(Method:="POST", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)> _
 Function ProcessXMLPayload(XML As String) As String

Comment: I think you could change the method parameter from string to use a class and then add the "any" member as shown above with the XmlAnyElement Attribute to the class.

Comment: Thanks it works, i change the xsd file and change the serialization from dataelement to xmlelement